# Execution error for task Program type already present

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Below is  my `build.gradle` and  error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.android.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.3-RELEASE'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
 }
```

The errors are below

> Error:Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate

Comment: Why you have `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` twice ? Try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079710/dexarchivemergerexception-with-android-studio-3-0) . See if it works .

Comment: sorry but now i removed but getting same issue